# Stuck with Firebase Rules - FirebaseError: The caller does not have permission

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

i do not seem to get firebase rules with Angular Fire App

./welcome.html

```
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="auth.ruling" (click)=" auth.kind() ">Add Data</button>
```

./auth.service.ts

```
kind(){
  this.resources.playSound('good')
  this.ruling = true;
  const uid = "dbrUo36xttQCAFRoxEqaa1Y1xdD3";

  // try update my own pKIN  
  return this.afs.doc(`${this.resources.env.db.users}/${uid}`).update({ 
    iAmKey: "Some Data", 
  }).then(ref => {
    this.ruling = false;
    console.log("DONE"); 
    return ref;
  }).catch(err => { 
    this.ruling = false; 
    console.log("ISSUE", err); 
    return err;
  });

}
```

./myFirestoreRules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function userSign(){ return request.auth != null }

    match /users/{ userId }/{docs = **} {
        
        allow get: // this works
            if true;

        allow list: // this works
            if !userSign() || userSign();

        allow update: // this does not work 
            if userSign();
        
    }

   }
  }
```

do i need to pass auth manually or is it automatic ?
if yes then how if no then whats wrong ?
can anyone help me...

Comment: Have you signed a user in via the Firebase Auth API? It looks like you are passing an arbitrary `uid` in the document path, but perhaps you want the current user's uid?

Comment: how do i use AngularFireAuth with AngularFirestore in an angular app. i mean do i need some extra code. i am stuck. my site works properly without rules. Why is that

Comment: @j1mbl3s how do i use AngularFireAuth with AngularFirestore in an angular app

Answer (score 0):

you must ensure the user is signed in and any values you use to query firestore are valid. when your client app reads from Firestore, it is also passing on any auth credentials from `Firebase.auth`.

if your user should meet the conditions in the rules, and is signed in when requesting the data, the process should succeed.

I would recommend checking the relevant documentation on Angular as well as any tutorials that cover the basics as this question covers a wide area of potential problems and will require debugging on your behalf.

Source:

- https://github.com/angular/angularfire
- https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/angularfire/

Comment: my issue is - even when my user is logged in Firebase.auth == null; Why is this happening. my rules work fine in emulator. My angular app is allergic. Please help me!

Comment: `firebase.auth` is a function to the Auth object, you want to check with `onAuthStateChanged()` and `firebase.auth().currentUser != null`  - - Reading AngularFire, it seems you should be able to access this with `$firebaseAuth` and it's appropriate methods

Answer (score 0):

- Cause of Error is not my code there was an issue with the @angularfire

Angularfire team will fix it soon i suppose
For now downgrade Angular app as well as @angularfire
wasted 4 days looking for fix, i should have tested rules with older projects first.